# Can not start ubuntu18 kvm guest

Tags: kvm

We setup kvm environment on linux host, and create 2 win7 and ubuntu18 guest vms.

We can start win7 guest, but ubuntu18 can not, pls refer to below definition xml.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

definition xml:

```
  <domain type='kvm'>
<name>ubuntu18</name>
<uuid>25184a13-922f-4f1f-96f8-c79bca7f5ead</uuid>
<memory>4000000</memory>
<currentMemory>4000000</currentMemory>
<vcpu>1</vcpu>
<os>
  <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-bionic'>hvm</type>
  <boot dev='hd'/>
  <boot dev='cdrom'/>
  <bootmenu enable='yes'/>
</os>
<features>
  <acpi/>
  <apic/>
  <pae/>
</features>
<clock offset='localtime'/>
<on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
<on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
<on_crash>restart</on_crash>
<devices>
  <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
  <disk type='file' device='disk'>
    <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
    <source file='/home/jenkins/kvm/image/ubuntu18.raw'/>
    <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
    <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
  </disk>
  <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
    <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
    <source file='/home/jenkins/kvm/iso/ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso'/>
    <target dev='hdb' bus='ide'/>
    <readonly/>
  </disk>

  <controller type='ide' index='0'>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
  </controller>
  <controller type='fdc' index='0'/>
  <interface type='bridge'>
    <mac address='fa:92:f9:30:83:a5'/>
    <source bridge='virbr0'/>
    <target dev='vnet0'/>
    <alias name='net0'/>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
  </interface>
  <serial type='pty'>
    <target port='0'/>
  </serial>
  <console type='pty'>
    <target type='serial' port='0'/>
  </console>
  <input type='tablet' bus='usb'/>
  <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
  <graphics type='vnc' port='5900' autoport='yes' listen='0.0.0.0' keymap='en-us'>
    <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
  </graphics>
  <sound model='ich6'>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
  </sound>
  <video>
    <model type='vga' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
  </video>
  <memballoon model='virtio'>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
  </memballoon>

</devices>
```